# Algebraic solution of complex equation

Tags: roots

For solving algebraically any complex equation involves two components for the real & imaginary parts. Let the real part be - $a$, imaginary part - $b$.
For the complex equation $$x^3 = 1-i $$

Substituting $x = a +bi$, we get: $$(a+bi)^3 = 1 - i.$$
Expanding the l.h.s. :
 $$a^3 -(b^3)i + 3(a^2)bi -3(b^2)a$$
Equating real and imaginary parts, we get:
$$  a^3 -3(b^2)a = 1  \tag{1}$$
$$  b^3 -3(a^2)b = 1  \tag{2}$$

Factoring $(1)$, $(2)$ to get some roots in the process:
$$a(a^2 - 3(b^2)) = 1 \tag{1'}$$
$$b(b^2 - 3(a^2)) = 1 \tag{2'}$$

From $(1')$, the roots are possibly given by equations below:

$$a = 1                      \tag{3}$$
$$  - \text{or} -  $$ // 'or' is used in logical or sense, i.e. either or both

$$ a^2 - 3(b^2) = 1          \tag{4}$$
Substituting $a = 1$ in $(4)$, we get:
$b = 0$; which cannot be a possible solution, as the right side of 
question has $b = -1$. Hence, $a \ne 1$ also.

Next, trying for the possible value from $(2')$.
$$ b = 1                      \tag{5} $$
$$  -\text{or}-  $$ // 'or' is used in logical or sense, i.e. either or both

$$ b^2 - 3(a^2) = 1          \tag{6} $$
Substituting $b = 1$ in $(6)$, we get:
$$ a = 0; $$
which cannot be a possible solution, as the right side of question 
has $a = 1$. Hence, $b \ne 1$ also.

I am unable to solve it further, as no solution emerges from the 
two equations - $(1')$, $(2')$.

Comment: Your equation (1') is in the form $AB = 1$, and you are concluding either $A=1$ or $B=1$.  This isn't valid.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang : Thanks for pointing the error.  But, I still don't know of how to get solution.

Comment: Everything below $(2')$ is rubbish

Comment: Robert has given you a hint in his answer below.

Comment: Introducing real and imaginary components only makes the problem more difficult. You should consider polar form of the equation instead

Comment: @MPW : It is a question from a book, and that asks for algebraic solution specifically.

Comment: Necessarily, if you insist on using this approach, you will need to solve a cubic. Mainly, $$a^3-3ab^2-1=0$$using your favorite method e.g. Cardano's method.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt : Thanks for pointing out this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here  is another solution, which you won't like because it is fundamentally geometric. It may not look geometric to you, but I only found it by looking at the picture.

Note that $(-1-i)^3=2-2i$. Therefore a  cube root of $1-i$ is $(-1-i)/\sqrt[3]2$.  The others are gotten by multiplying this answer by $\omega$ and $\omega^2$, where $\omega=\frac12(-1+\sqrt{-3})$.

(Thanks fly out to Michael Hardy for the correction.)

Comment: Don't you need $\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{-3}} { \sqrt[3]2} \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: Please provide the link for the picture.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, absolutely. Thanks for spotting my carelessness.

Comment: @jiten, there is no link, nor did I even write the picture down. It’s a picture you draw in your mind.

Comment: Can you please tell why cube of (-1 -i) was taken. It is the mirror image in the y axis of (1 -i).

Comment: OK, here’s the picture. Ignoring the absolute value for the moment, since the argument of $1-i$ is $-45^\circ$, a cube root has argument $-15^\circ$. The other cube roots are off that by $\pm120^\circ$. Which of these adds up to a diagonal angle $\pm135^\circ$? You get $-15-120=-135$, so that you want $-1-i$. Cube it, and correct the absolute value by dividing (not multiplying, sorry for the error) by $\sqrt[3]2$.

Comment: I am thankful for giving insight into the reason for choosing (-1 -i).

Answer (score 5):

No, this is wrong.  $a(a^2 - 3 b^2) = 1$ does not imply $a=1$ or $a^2-3b^2=1$.  For example, you might have $a = 2$ and $a^2 - 3 b^2 = 1/2$.

It's usually not helpful to look at real and imaginary parts in an equation such as this.  A better idea would be to use the polar representation: $x = r e^{i\theta}$,
$1-i = \sqrt{2} e^{-i\pi/4}$.

Comment: No, I want an algebraic solution; provided it is possible to do so. It seems that it is not.

Comment: In my world, the above suggestion *is* an algebraic solution.

Comment: I cannot gather by "my world". Either it is, or it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$a^3-3b^2a=b^3-3a^2b=1 \implies a^3-b^3+3a^2b-3b^2a=0$$ which implies 
$$(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)+3ab(a-b)=0 \implies (a-b)(a^2+4ab+b^2)=0.$$
As such, $a=b$ or $a^2 + 4ab+b^2 = a^2+4ab+4b^2-3b^2 = 0 \implies a = (-2 \pm \sqrt{3})b.$

If $a=b$ then $a^3-3b^2a = -2a^3=1 \implies \color{red}{a=b=-2^{-1/3}}$.

I leave the calculations for $a=(-2 \pm \sqrt{3})b$ to you.

An alternative way of computing the remaining roots (as also suggested by some other people) is given below.

Let $x_0 = -2^{-1/3}-2^{-1/3}i=-2^{-1/3}(1+i)$. We just found out that $x_0^3 = 1-i$. Now
$$x^3 = 1-i \implies \left(\frac{x}{x_0}\right)^3 = \frac{1-i}{x_0^3}=1.$$
Let $y = x/x_0$. We are looking for the solution of $y^3-1=0$. But 
$$y^3-1 = (y-1)(y^2+y+1)=0 \implies y=1 \quad \text{ or }\quad y^2+y+1=0. $$
Now $y=1 \implies x=x_0$, and $$y^2+y+1 = 0 \implies y = \frac{x}{x_0}= \frac{-1\pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}.$$
As such, the remaining cube roots of $1-i$ are $$-2^{-1/3}(1+i)\left(\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}\right).$$

Comment: Seems that I am making a error is further processing as there are now two equations: $$ a-b =0  -(i) ,  a^2 +4ab+b^2   -(ii)$$                                              Substituting the value of a=b in (ii), we get $$6b^2=0$$                               This is leading to a=b=0.

Comment: @jiten We do not substitute $a=b$ in $(ii)$. Observe that we have three solutions of $x^3=1-i$. The first solution corresponds to $a=b$, which I have provided in the updated answer.

Comment: The other 2 values (2nd, 3rd) of a are: 

$$(-2 + \sqrt(3)).b  \;\; \;\;\;-(ii) $$ 
$$(-2 - \sqrt(3)).b   \;\;\;\;\;-(iii) $$

Substituting (ii) in (1):
$$b=  {(5 + \sqrt[2]{3})/8)}^{1/3}, a = (-2 + \sqrt(3)).{(5 + \sqrt[2]{3})/8)}^{1/3}$$
Substituting (iii) in (1):
$$b=  \sqrt[3]{(5 - \sqrt[2]{3})/8)}, a = (-2 - \sqrt(3)).\sqrt[3]{(5 - \sqrt[2]{3})/8)} $$

Comment: @jiten Your answer might be correct. You can verify the correctness of your solution on wolfram alpha by cubing $(a+ib)$. An alternative way of computing the remaining roots is provided in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use polar form to find one root, then back into an algebraic solution.

$1-i= 2^{1/2}e^{-i\pi/4}$, so $(2^{1/6}e^{-i\pi/12})^3=1-i$ (there are other solutions as well).

Now write one solution $\sqrt[6]{2}\cos \pi/12 - i\sqrt[6]{2}\sin\pi/12$ in algebraic terms, then divide the appropriate linear factor from the original equation $z^3 - 1 + i =0$. That's not going to be easy.

Then you have a quadratic factor remaining, which gives its roots via the quadratic formula.

It's not too hard to show $\sin\pi/12=(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})/4$ and the cosine formula is similar but with "$+$" instead of "$-$". These come from considering $\sin(\pi/3-\pi/4)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $1-i= \sqrt 2 (\cos315^\circ + i\sin315^\circ),$ the cube roots of $1-i$ must be
$$
2^{1/6} (\cos(105^\circ+n120^\circ) + i\sin(105^\circ+n120^\circ))
$$
where the only values of $n$ we need to consider are $0,$ $1,$ and $2.$

If we can believe the tables on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals), we have
$$
\cos105^\circ = -\frac 1 4 (\sqrt 6 - \sqrt 2\,) \quad \text{and} \quad \sin(105^\circ) = \frac 1 4 (\sqrt6 + \sqrt 2\,).
$$
(The page gives $\cos15^\circ = \dfrac 1 4 ( \sqrt 6 + \sqrt 2\,)$ and $\sin15^\circ = \dfrac 1 4 (\sqrt 6 - \sqrt 2\,).$ If you consider $\dfrac 1 2 = \sin30^\circ = 2\sin15^\circ\cos15^\circ,$ then this appears to make sense. And then $\cos105^\circ = -\sin15^\circ$ and $\sin105^\circ = \cos15^\circ$ since $105 = 15 +90.$)

So we should have
$$
\sqrt 2\,\left( -\frac 1 4(\sqrt6-\sqrt2\,) + i \frac 1 4( \sqrt6+\sqrt 2\,) \right)^3 = 1-i.
$$

Comment: But, the page referenced as per the link is not showing any tables.

Comment: @jiten : By a "table" I mean something like this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals#15.C2.B0:_regular_dodecagon_.2812-sided_polygon.29

Answer (score 1):

Someone has pointed out that one solution of $x^3 - (1-i) =0$ is $\dfrac{-1-i}{\sqrt[3]2}.$

Therefore $x+\dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt[3]2}$ is a factor of $x^3 - (1-i).$ So we can do long division:

$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
& & & & x^2 & - & \dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt[3]2}x & + & i\sqrt[3]2  \\ \\
x + \dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt[3]2} & \Big) & x^3 & + & 0x^2 & + & 0x & - & (1-i) \\
& & x^3 & + & \dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt[3]2} x^2 \\  \\  \\
& & & & -\dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt[3]2} x^2 & & & - & (1-i) \\
& & & & -\dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt[3]2} x^2 & - & i x \sqrt[3]2 \\  \\  \\
& & & & & & ix\sqrt[3]2 & - & (1-i) \\
& & & & & & ix\sqrt[3]2 & - & (1-i) \\  \\  \\
& & & & & & & & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Thus we have found that
$$
x^3-(1-i) = \left( x + \frac{1+i}{\sqrt[3]2} \right) \left( x^2 - \frac{1+i}{\sqrt[3]2} x + i\sqrt[3]2 \right).
$$
The other two solutions are now solutions of a quadratic equation. If we write the equation as $ax^2+bx+c=0$ then we have $a=1,$ $b= - \dfrac{1+i}{\sqrt[3]2},$ and $c=i\sqrt[3]2,$ and
$$
b^2-4ac = -3i\sqrt[3]2.
$$
So what is $\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac~} \text{ ?}$ We just saw that $(1+i)^2 = 2i,$ i.e. $\pm\sqrt{2i} = \pm(1+i),$ so that gives us $\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac~}.$

Answer (score 0):

Square both sides:

$(x^2)^3=-2i=2(-i)=2i^3$

Then

$x^2=(2^{1/3})i$

for one root.

Now just divide the $x^3$ from your original equation by $x^2$ as given above and you have a root for $x$!  You then get the others by multiplying by the complex cube roots of unity.